# Adjusting queries to indexes

Tags: mysql

I have got this table

```
type smallint(6)
category smallint(6)
subcategory smallint(6)
name varchar(175)
```

sometimes I need to execute this query:

```
select * from table where type = x and category = y and subcategory = z
```

other times, I need to execute this one:

```
select * from table where type = x and category = y
```

so, I have created two indexes, so the queries run very fast (since the table has got million rows)

```
alter table table add index A (type,category,subcategory);
alter table table add index B (type,category);
```

My question is, to speed up 'updates', 'inserts', etc, could I **remove** the second index, and change the second query into this:

```
select * from table where type = x and category = y and subcategory >= 0
```

That way, that query would be using the index A, as well as the first query. Index B wouldn't be used and I would be able to remove it to speed up inserts and updates.

Something is telling me I have to be wrong with this, it just seems a bit farfetched...

What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nobody can answer this correctly if you dont provide the output of `show create table [table_name]` and some `explain [your_query]` outputs... Correct indexing is like art... and an range scan subcategory >= 0 may need un completly different index this depends on the index selectivity of category, type and subcategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gray has it right. Check out the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

You don't need both of your example indices A and B. You would need something like `index X (category, subcategory)` or `index Y (type, subcategory)` if you need such index order in your queries.

With your `index A (type,category,subcategory)` you cover both of your example queries (the second query doesn't need the `subcaterory >= 0` part, just leave it out) and also query: `select * from table where type = x`.

Comment: Wow, mysql is getting cooler by the minute. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Index A (type,category,subcategory) can be used to speedup queries like

```
select * from table where type = x and category = y
```

So you may safely delete B and don't rewrite queries. Also index A can act like index C (type), but not as index D (category).